# Connection to SQL server - Failed

Tags: databaselink, sql

I have a test database created by the colleagues from IT department and I can also access / see it using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2016. However, I cannot establish a connection to it from within Mathematica notebook...
I read the documentation but I'm not confident with databases in general, so maybe I make a basic mistake somewhere.
What I do is:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
conn = OpenSQLConnection[]
```

That opens the Connection Tool GUI, where I define the new connection:

- define the name and description of database (test / test database);
- visibility (user level);
- type of database (Microsoft SQL Server jTDS);
- Connection: Hostname (wwe***pe.**.***.ds\MSSQL***); Port (1433); Database (empty); Attributes (empty); Username (****); Password (*******).

The hostname, username and password are the ones which I use (and worked) for connecting to database via MS SQL Server Management Studio.
At this stage, when I push the "Test" button, I get after a few seconds the error message

```
Error: JDBC::error
```

On the next page, "Connection properties", I leave everything unchanged, than I click "Finish". Now, when I try

```
conn = OpenSQLConnection["test"]
```

I get (almost obviously) the error

```
JDBC::error: Unknown server host name 'wwe**pe.**.***.ds\MSSQL***'. 
$Failed
```

It would be nice if somebody could guide me to solve this connection issue.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that the server host name is in error.  This is because the instance name has been tacked onto the end of server host name (*wwe**pe.**.***.ds\MSSQL****).  While this is valid syntax using OLEDB or .NET drivers, the jTDS driver requires the host name (*www**pe.**.***.ds*) to be specified separately from the instance name (*MSSQL****).  The instance name must be supplied as a connection property.

At step 5 of the connection wizard, specify the *Hostname* alone:

[image: connection wizard screenshot]

At step 6, specify the instance name as a property:

[image: connection wizard screenshot]

At this point, it should be possible to establish a connection (assuming the other connection parameters are correct).